# SSHing in to EC2 Ubuntu instance with user ubuntu tells me to login as ubuntu

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm having an issue where I try to SSH into my API server (EC2 instance running Ubuntu). I've been SSH'ing in just fine for the past few weeks, but I suspect I messed something up because now it tells me to login as user ubuntu (I am!) :

```
% ssh ubuntu@ec2-50-17-143-255.compute-1.amazonaws.com -i ~/dev/key.pem
Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".
```

Is there something I could have done to mess with the ubuntu user? Is there anyway to resolve this without having to save the AMI and boot up a new instance?

Comment: check the key, probably it's root's key, not ubuntu's

Comment: sorry, could you elaborate? I've been using this same key (key.pem) the entire time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `ssh -v ...` or `ssh -vv ...` to see what is going on.

In your case it looks like you copied ~root/.ssh/authorized_keys to ~ubuntu/.ssh/.

According to [this](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-server-bugs/2011-June/057863.html), the root account is configured to reject logins with this message using the authorized_keys file. If you copied this file, now the user ubuntu will reject logins with this key, too...

Comment: also [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/388628/scp-to-aws-ec2-error-please-login-as-the-user-ubuntu-rather-than-the-user) is similar.

Comment: that's exactly what I did, thank you. I don't know how to recover from this however, so I guess I'll have to boot up a new instance. thanks again